# A text string "pages" is added after each citation in the bibliography section

Tags: bibtex

I'm facing the following problem with the bibliography output format: after each citation, a text string "pages" is added (see picture)

[image: Citation print format]

Do you suspect what could be wrong?

---

I solved the problem by not importing the package *backref*.

---

Using the *backref* package:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{backref}
    \begin{document}
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \section*{Section}
            A citation lies here \cite{freeman:1977}.
        \bibliography{bibliography}
        \bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Without using the *backref* package:

```
\documentclass{article}
    %\usepackage{backref}
    \begin{document}
        \thispagestyle{empty}
        \section*{Section}
            A citation lies here \cite{freeman:1977}.
        \bibliography{bibliography}
        \bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Isn't this the expected behavior for `backref`? The purpose of the package is to list, after each reference in the bibliography, the pages where the reference was cited (apparently introducing the page numbers with the string `pages`). If you don't want these back-references, then don't use the `backref` package.